# Relativizing absolute paths in an Emacs buffer

Tags: regex, emacs, relative-path, absolute-path

I find myself with a mix of absolute (auto-generated via `org-structure-template-alist`) and relative paths (written by hand) in my buffer.

Attempt at a solution:

```
(let ((curdir (replace-regexp-in-string
               (expand-file-name "~/") "~/"
               (file-name-directory
                (or load-file-name buffer-file-name)))))
  (replace-regexp (concat "\"" curdir "(?1:([A-z]|[0-9]|/)*)" "\"") "\1")
  (message curdir))
```

But it doesn't seem to be working at all.  This was a attempt to fix an almost-working version that only fails to remove surrounding quotes:

```
(replace-regexp curdir "")
```

---

Third attempt:

```
(replace-regexp (concat ":tangle \"" curdir "\([A-z-+/.]+\)\"") "\1")
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to match quoted absolute paths under your HOME directory, and convert them into unquoted relative paths, so how about:

```el
(replace-regexp
 (concat "\"" (regexp-quote (expand-file-name "~/")) "\\(.*?\\)\"")
 "\\1")
```

I suspect most of your problems stem from not understanding Emacs' regexp syntax, and the additional escaping requirements when representing a regexp with a string, as you have various errors in these areas.

In particular, remember that Emacs regexps use `\( \)` for grouping (or `\(?: \)` for non-capturing groups), and that in strings you need to escape all backslashes which are part of the regexp syntax. You should read the following:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Syntax for Strings` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Regular Expressions` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Also, note the use of `regexp-quote` when incorporating non-literal values into a regexp. (All regexp-supporting languages will have an analogous function to this, and not using it is asking for trouble.)

I strongly recommend using <kbd>M-x</kbd> `regexp-builder` <kbd>RET</kbd> to interactively build your regexp. This will undoubtedly save you a lot of frustration, wondering why your pattern isn't matching what you expected it to.